# Unity UI Button, strange behavior with triggering OnClick()

Tags: android, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

Using Unity 5.0.
Working on Android.

I simply have a Canvas -> with inside a Panel -> with inside a Button.

The Button has in its Button script the OnClick() with a GameObject linked. 
The GameObject has a script with a function.

When I tap the button I simply trigger the function, which is working properly on Unity.

But when I deploy the project on an Android (4.4.2) device, it works only if you tap and leave the finger very fast. Otherwise if you tap and wait just a second, when you remove the finger the OnClick() is not called anymore.

Seems like it is triggering a sort of "long tap" and it is ignoring my normal tap. I am missing some seetings? I have not much code at all, just the function, the rest is all done via Unity inspector.

Comment: Please remove the "Unity" tag.  If you're curious as to why, hover over the "Unity" tag.

Answer (score 3):

You probably suffer from the same problem I did. Check the value for "Drag Threshold" for the "Event System (script)" which you will find in the inspector once you select the EventSystem in the hierarchy.
The default value is 5 which is tiny and anything but the briefest of touches will not register as a click but as a drag. Increase the size. I use 20 and my buttons now work as expected on Android. Which reminds me I have to check this now on iOS again as well.

Good luck